# How can I get an interface from its implementation class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface, callback

In my Android app I have a controller `DataManager` where I do some data transfer stuff and I have defined (amongst others) an interface `ProgressbarCallback` to show the progress in another depending Fragment:

```
public class DataManager {

    ProgressbarCallback progressbarCallback;

    public interface ProgressbarCallback {
        void updateProgress(int progress);
    }

    //2
    ProgressShowerFragment f = ProgressShowerFragment.getInstance();
    progressCallback = f.getCallback();

    //3
    progressCallback.updateProgress(i)
}
```

there I would like to control the progressbar of a depending Fragment. So I have a `ProgressShowerFragment` to show my progress:

```
public class ProgressShowerFragment extends Fragment implements DataManager.ProgressbarCallback {

    @Override
    public void updateProgress(int progress) {
        progresBar.setProgress(progress);
    }

    //1
    public ProgressbarCallback getCallback(){
        return this;
    } 
}
```

To have a reference in my `DataManager` I have done a getter (see 1) what returns the Callback. When instantiating `ProgressShowerFragment` I also get that Callback (see 2).

Later on usage I update the progress like in 3.

**For me this seem very ugly. What is an elegant way to do get the Callback?**

Comment: Getter isn't needed. ProgressShowerFragment already implements callback, so you can just `progressCallback = ProgressShowerFragment.getInstance();`  

What exactly seems ugly for you?

Comment: You can cast f to **ProgressbarCallback**  `((ProgressbarCallback) f).updateProgress(i) `

Comment: @SergeyGlotov I instantiate and show that fragment in an internat method in `DataManager`.. But the updateProgress I call from several places, so I had to make my fragment a member variable of `DataManager`. I tried to avoid using member variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast f to ProgressbarCallback

```
((ProgressbarCallback) f).updateProgress(i)
```

Comment: It is also woreking without cast. ok I have the ProgressShowerFragment as a member variable now.